# Illegal character in VS 2017 Resource system

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

I have this line of code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText(Properties.Resources.settings));
```

AndI get this error message:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.'
```

I have added the file "settings.xml" as a resource to my project in Visual Studio 2017 Community.

The path to my  project is:

```
C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Projects\Test\Test\Resources
```

Comment: What is the value of `Properties.Resources.settings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `settings` is the file you already added, you will get the contents. That's the point of the resource system, that you don't need to read from files:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(Properties.Resources.settings);
```